# How I can find if string exists inside mongodb Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to find document based on profileID in MongoDB. I want to check if string postid exists in array or not. How I can do that? I tried `$all`.

Mongo data:

```
{
  "profileId": "abc",
  "likedPosts": [
    'post1',
    'post2'
  ]
}
```

Trying to find if post1 exists in array:

```
findOne({
  profileId
}, {
  likedPosts: {
    $all: ['post1']
  }
}, )
```

Comment: Did you try with $in?
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if a string exists in an array field you can simply do:

```
findOne({
  profileId,
  likedPosts: 'post1'
  }
}, )
```

[Docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-an-array-for-an-element)

Also you might notice i have made the whole query as the first parameter. The second parameter is usually the callback to run, once the query has executed.